# Why "last *" command of Apache IoTDB cannot query out all the points and values?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

There is a strange problem I found here in Apache IoTDB. I used "`select last * from [path_name]`", and the query result does not display some points and the values of these points. However, if I use "`select last point from [path_name]`", I can still check the value of the points that were missing in the before statement. Does anyone know why this problem occurs?